# how to setup multicurrency ICO / Crowdsale

Tags: solidity, ico, crowdsale

I'm having difficulty finding information on how to setup a contract that accepts multi-currency like bitcoin, wave, ripple, etc. And also looking for a solution to distribute my tokens to these accepted coins.

A direction or links on how to setup these steps would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can we create wallet by using Blockchain.info API? something like this https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive They have api to create ETH and BTC wallete and have api to know the balance of wallet

Comment: one problem with blockchain.info that they don't allow you to send directly to a Smart Contract address

Comment: Just give them link to to a tutorial. It is not worth of the problem, as buyers need to have an Ethereum wallet to manage their tokens in any case. https://tokenmarket.net/what-is/how-to-participate-in-ethereum-token-sale-and-pay-with-bitcoin/

Answer (score 5):

An Ethereum contract cannot directly interact with other blockchains.

You have to use a service like [BTC Relay](http://btcrelay.org/), their [project on github](https://github.com/ethereum/btcrelay).

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your own bitcoin, litecoin, etc node to accept payments on your server and then in your system call your smart contract / send the tokens to the appropriate address of the depositor.

They will have to register and then a bitcoin address would be generated from your servers bitcoin node so you can connect it to that user once funds are sent.. then send the tokens to that users ethereum address on file that they set when signing up.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be a solution something like this. I am just thinking.

1. Generate bitcoin public address and private address using php script and store in a database
2. user transaction ID and call transaction API to confirm the payment has received.(in this case the question which service provider will provide the transaction api service? is there any open hosted api by which we can check the incremental balance of a bitcoin address by using transaction id?)
3. import your private key in any wallet provider. or set up your own node. and import your private key.